# Same date for every 2 rows?

Tags: excel

I didn't know exactly how to describe this so I thought an example would be the best way to illustrate what I mean. I want to input dates like this:

```
Cell A1 = March 1, 2017
Cell A2 = March 1, 2017
Cell A3 = March 2, 2017
Cell A4 = March 2, 2017
Cell A5 = March 3, 2017
Cell A6 = March 3, 2017
```

and so on...

Is there a faster way to do this than simply inputting it manually?

Comment: Just put `=A1+1` in A3 and `=A2+1` in A4, select range A3:A4  and pull down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the DATE() function with a little math for the day:

```
=DATE(2017,3,1)+(ROW()-1)/2
```

Then drag down

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=DATE(2017,3,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/2,0))
```

and copy down.

[image]

Comment: @RayJani now you need to mark one as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  Mark the one you used.  Neither of us will be angry if the other is chosen, both are good answers, just slightly different approaches.